# Останавливается прокрутка в NestedScrollView

Tags: android, xml, layout, nested-scrollview

Останавливается прокрутка в NestedScrollView при свернутом Toolbar. Отображаются не все данные. Как это возможно исправить?

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:colorBackground"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.SubtitleCollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            app:contentScrim="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <com.example.projectintent.additional.ScaleImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageProfilePurpose"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textProfileDescription"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/sheet_text_scrim_height_top"
                android:background="@drawable/scrim_top"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/sheet_text_scrim_height_bottom"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="@drawable/scrim_bottom" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbarPurpose"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.SubtitleCollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    
    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPagerPurpose"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabViewPagerLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            app:tabGravity="center"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabPaddingBottom="8dp"
            app:tabPaddingEnd="16dp"
            app:tabPaddingStart="16dp"
            app:tabPaddingTop="8dp"
            app:tabTextColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary" />
    </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

После разделителя ---- должны идти 1/n2/n3/n4/n5...

[image]

Внес правки при котором все работает (отсутствовал атрибут android:fillViewport="true"), кроме одного момента. Теперь у меня прокручивается список, но не полностью. Но при переходе из одной вкладки ViewPager в другую и обратно - он прокручивается полностью. Может дело в ViewPager?

Comment: попробуйте у скролла установить тоже fill_parent а не match_parent может что-то изменится. Можно посмотреть через инспектор макета что и как у вас отображается. Судя по скрину у вас данные загружены но не могут адекватно отобразиться

Comment: Andrew, я обновил ответ, может есть комментарий по обновленному вопросу?